# Java generics - generic method doesnt compile

Tags: java, generics

Hi I have a class SomeClass and a private map that I want to have in values list of objects A and B where B extends A.

The below code doesnt compile.. I cant change anything in class name, it must be left like:

```
public class SomeClass {
<T extends ParentObject> Map<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: Your generic parameter should be on the class: `SomeClass<T extends ParentObject>`

Comment: You cannot have generic fields. The type declaration needs to be on either the class or a method.

Comment: I use java 1.7 and I cand change SomeClass as I said to SomeClass<T extends ParentObject> I can only change method i wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After class's name definiton

```
public class SomeClass<T extends ParentObject>  {
Map<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: I use java 1.7 and I cand change SomeClass as I said to SomeClass<T extends ParentObject> I can only change method i wrote

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends ParentObject> {
    Map<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: I use java 1.7 and I cand change SomeClass as I said to SomeClass<T extends ParentObject> I can only change method i wrote

Comment: So you should move operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap to a function and return it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on java version which u are using. If u are using java 1.7 or higher, then u can use:

```
 public class SomeClass<T extends ParentObject>  {
        Map<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap = 
                               new HashMap<>();
    }
```

If u have 1.6 or earlier, then:

```
   public class SomeClass<T extends ParentObject>  {
        Map<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap = 
                               new HashMap<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>>();
    }
```

To introduce method with generics just write:

```
private <T extends ParentObject> Map<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap() {
    return new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: I use java 1.7 and I cand change SomeClass as I said to SomeClass<T extends ParentObject> I can only change method i wrote

Comment: You wrote not a method, but a field, and you cant set generics to your field like u show in your question. To introduce generics to method write:
private <T extends ParentObject> Map<SignedOperationNameEnum, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap()
{return new HashMap<>();}

Comment: THANKS.. that what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the types you are using for instance this code which is very similar to yours compiles and runs  perfectly on 1.7.

```
public class SomeClass {

    static <T extends Number> Map<Integer, List<T>> operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap() {
        return null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(operationToOrderStateSkipSignatureSetMap());
    }
}
```